# REE Installation

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am trying to Install Ruby EE on my machine but am not able to. 
`ping production.cf.rubygems.org` also works. What may be the problem?

```
prashanth@prashanth-laptop:~/Downloads$ rvm install ree
Installing Ruby Enterprise Edition from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 - #fetching (ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   184    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03.tar.gz
  0 7713k    0 16150    0     0   3108      0  0:42:21  0:00:05  0:42:16 17497
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16150)
ERROR: There was an error, please check /usr/local/rvm/log/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/*.log. Next we'll try to fetch via http.
Trying http:// URL instead.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   184    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03.tar.gz

  0 7713k    0 16150    0     0   4375      0  0:30:05  0:00:03  0:30:02 18692

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16150)
ERROR: There was an error, please check /usr/local/rvm/log/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/*.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the source. 
Halting the installation.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the log file contents?

Answer (score 5):

The message:

```
Warning: Failed to create the file ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03.tar.gz
```

Is your clue. You're running a machine-wide install of RVM, but trying to install a new ruby as a user without root access.

Try:

```
rvmsudo rvm install ree
```

Or login as root and retry the command.

Comment: If it's a development machine, you'd better just uninstall RVM (using `rvm implode`) then reinstall it as a regular user. Running RVM as root on a development machine is a PITA.